# Usage of OpenMP reduction clause with nested loops

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

I have the current version of a function:

```
    void*
    function(const Input_st *Data, Output_st *Image)
    {
        int i,j,r,Offset;
        omp_set_num_threads(24);
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) shared(Data,Image),\ 
        private(i,j,r,Offset)
        for (i = 0; i < Data->NX; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < (Data->NZ); j++)
            {
                for (r = 0; r < Data->NR; r++)
                {
                    Offset                = i*Data->NR*Data->NZ + j*Data->NR + r;
                    Image->pTime[Offset] = function2()
                }
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

It works very well, however I wanted to remove the calculation of the variable Offset and use of a pointer pointing to the member `Image->pTimeR` and then increment, which can look like following:

```
    void*
    function(const Input_st *Data, Output_st *Image)
    {
        int i, j, r;
        double *pTime = Image->pTime;
        omp_set_num_threads(24);
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) shared(Data,Image),\ 
        private(i,j,r)
        for (i = 0; i < Data->NX; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < (Data->NZ); j++)
            {
                for (r = 0; r < Data->NR; r++)
                {
                    *pTime = function2()
                    pTime++;
                }
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

I get Seg Fault. I assume I need to use the `reduction` clause like `reduction(+:pTime)`.

1. First, the purpose here is to speed up the function and I am wondering if such change would significantly speed up? (Like less cache memory used?)
2. Second, well I tried to benchmark it and failed to do so! I think the problem here can be solved by using a reduction clause, but since loops are nested the problem is not that straightforward to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need of any sort of `reduction` clause here. However,at the moment, all threads use the same pointer and update the same memory location (with race conditions in the value assigned to `pTime`, hence the crashes I suspect).

So you need to define your pointer in a private way (typically by declaring it within the `parallel` region, and to set it individually per thread to a meaningful value. Then it can be incremented the way you want.

Here is what the code could look like once fixed (not tested obviously):

```
void* function( const Input_st *Data, Output_st *Image ) {
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule( static ) num_threads( 24 )
    for ( int i = 0; i < Data->NX; i++ ) {
        double *pTime = Image->pTime + i * Data->NR * Data->NZ;
        for ( int j = 0; j < Data->NZ; j++ ) {
            for ( int r = 0; r < Data->NR; r++ ) {
                *pTime = function2();
                pTime++;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I tried it by replacing the *pTime declaration in the j loop (instead of i since the Offset depends on j) and it worked! However I dont see a significant improvement in terms of performance! Thanks!!